# Changing color of dynamically created div returns "TypeError: Cannot set property 'background' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a div that renders with a random color when the page loads and a button that creates a div inside of him once the user clicks on him. I am trying to add a random color to the newly created div (leaf) but I get this error:

> TypeError: Cannot set property 'background' of undefined

When I console.log my leaf I receive a node, so it's not undefined. How can I fix this error and add my random color to the leaf? Here is my code:

```html
<template>
  <div id="parent-branch">
    <h1>Branch (B 0) (L 0) {{mycolor}}</h1>
    <div class="button-container">
      <button>Add Branch</button>
      <button @click="addLeaf">Add Leaf</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
      return {
        mycolor: '#'+(Math.random()*0xFFFFFF<<0).toString(16)
      }
  },
    mounted() {
     document.getElementById('parent-branch').style.background = this.mycolor;
  },
    methods: {
     colorGenerator() {
        this.mycolor = '#'+(Math.random()*0xFFFFFF<<0).toString(16);
        document.getElementById('parent-branch').style.background = this.mycolor;
       },

     addLeaf() {
      var div = document.createElement('div');
      div.className = 'leaf'
      var leaf = document.querySelectorAll('.leaf');
      leaf.style.background = this.mycolor;
      var container = document.getElementById('parent-branch');
      container.appendChild(div)

     },
    },
  name: 'ParentBranch',
}
</script>

<style scoped>
.parent-branch {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
}
</style>
```

Comment: `leaf` is a `NodeList`, which does not have a `style` property. It is `style` that is undefined, that is why the error says "Cannot set property 'background' of undefined".

Answer (score 0):

When you use `document.querySelectorAll`, it returns an array of elements.
You have to loop over all elements and change `style.background` of each of them.

So `addLeaf` method has to change like this:

```
addLeaf() {
      var div = document.createElement('div');
      div.className = 'leaf'
      var leaf = document.querySelectorAll('.leaf');
      leaf.forEach(l => l.style.background = this.mycolor)
      var container = document.getElementById('parent-branch');
      container.appendChild(div)
    },
```

Also not relevant to your question, but when you create branches and leaves, there's no content in it. It gets added to the DOM but doesn't display anything since it's empty.

I've also changed addLeaf to contain some text:

```
addLeaf() {
      var div = document.createElement('div');
      div.className = 'leaf'
      div.innerText = "hi"
      var leaf = document.querySelectorAll('.leaf');
      leaf.forEach(l => l.style.background = this.mycolor)
      var container = document.getElementById('parent-branch');
      container.appendChild(div)
    },
```